# Why is my C# IS statement not working?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I have the following code, where T is a generic defined as such:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class, IDataModel
```

This code works just fine:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
if (propertyInfo.DeclaringType.FullName == typeof(T).FullName)  <--- Works just fine
```

vs this code which evaluates to false

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
if (propertyInfo.DeclaringType is T) <-- does not work
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4XT-l-_3y0

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) uses type comparison between the two objects. So `DeclaringType` is of type `Type` and `typeof(T)` is of type `T`, which are not equal.

```
var aType = typeof(propertyInfo.DeclaringType);
var bType = typeof(T);
bool areEqual = aType is bType; // Always false, unless T is Type
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is

[TypeIsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx)

```
if (propertyInfo.DeclaringType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
```